# Как включить разметку html в TelegramClient на python from telethon

Tags: python

Как включить разметку html  в TelegramClient

```
client.send_message('me', '<b>bold</b> <i>italic</i>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо передавать `parse_mode` при каждом вызове `client.send_message`:

```py
client.send_message("me", "<b>bold</b>", parse_mode="html")
client.send_message("me", "<i>italic</i>", parse_mode="html")
```

Либо использовать переменную `client.parse_mode`:

```py
client.parse_mode = "html"

client.send_message("me", "<b>bold</b>")
client.send_message("me", "<i>italic</i>")
```

По умолчанию telethon использует Markdown:

```py
client.send_message("me", "**bold**")
client.send_message("me", "__italic__")
```

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message

Comment: Спасибо. Только почему-то перенос строк <br> не работает пока пишу через \n